# Slime Farm Issues

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need help because I want to build a slime farm I have found chunks using a slime chunk finder. I have built it below level 40 at 35, It's a 16 by 16 area and I have triple checked my coordinates and seed. I have placed jack o' lanterns spaced out on it. It is in fact 3 blocks tall. I at one point left the area more than 25 blocks away and less than 40 for about 4 hours! and not a single slime has spawned. What can I do or what am I doing wrong.

Comment: is it in peaceful? And what biome?

Comment: It is Normal in a forest biome within a slime chunk.

Answer (score 2):

If you've found this slime chink in a Swamp biome, they will spawn between layers 50-70. However, everywhere else they will spawn below layer 40, so you should be fine there. You'll need to be between 25 and 32 blocks away. Assuming you've met all of these—the slimes should spawn. Of course, I'm assuming you are playing on a difficulty other than peaceful.

Comment: I have built it in a slime chunk i have built the same thing in a swamp but it still didnt work. I have lit caves up nearby I also have moved the pad to level 10. Still no spawns. Seed: 545643967389872387.     My coords are -177 -833 to -191 -847